# Redirect old domain to new domain... all pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two domains pointed to the same directory on my hosting account. I want to use .htaccess to redirect the old one to the new one. This is what I used:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shavara.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.shavara.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.shavararcm.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The entire code is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shavara.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.shavara.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.shavararcm.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

If I type shavara.com into the browser it goes to shavararcm.com but if I type:

```
https://www.shavara.com/industry-solutions/iridium-suite-for-medical-oncology-billing
```

it doesn't go to:

```
https://www.shavararcm.com/industry-solutions/iridium-suite-for-medical-oncology-billing
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your code *above* WordPress' default code.

This is because WordPress will already do a rewrite for paths which don't exist as real files, and it specifies the `[L]` modifier which means "last". So your rewrite will be ignored if the previous rewrite matches.

*In case of your code it is fine that it has `[L]` because it also has `[R=301]` which causes a "real" redirect anyway, so WordPress' rewrites should happen on the following request and not the current one.*